# Python 3.8: require 2nd letter as uppercase value in password

Tags: python-3.x, string, while-loop, integer, uppercase

I have to ask user to enter password which meets specific requirements like:

- *minimum 8 long;*
- *contain at least on number;*
- *to have at least one capital letter;*

First three requirements I have solved but I'm unable to find solution for:

- *second letter has to be capital;*

What should be in algorithm that checks if correct value is entered?

I guess `string.upper()` wont help me in this case because I need to ask user for correct input value not converting existing one.

Kind regards,
J.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.isupper()` function to check if a character is uppercase.

```
string = "aBcdef"

if string[1].isupper():
    # second letter is uppercase
```

For your case, I would be careful since you are also asking for a number in the password. You have to make sure the second character is not a number when you check it for uppercase because it will return `false`.